# UILocalNotification alternative for iOS3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am building an iPhone application and I want to use UILocalNotification to schedule an alarm for an event. The problem is that UILocalNotification only works from iOS4, and I want to try and make my application compatible with iOS3 too.

I have found a way to detect if UILocalNotification is available on given iOS version. I am now wondering if there is an alternative for UILocalNotification that can be used on an iPhone with iOS3 to schedule an alarm or notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push notification are your only option.

They requires a network connection, a server of your own and are way more complicated to implement then local notification but are the only way to go in iOS 3.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of :(